# Difference between Eureka Discovery vs Service Registry (PCF)

Tags: spring-boot, service-discovery

In start.spring.io, I can find Eureka Discovery and Service Registry (PCF), seems like they are the same. what's the different between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They indeed are same. PCF's Service Registry is based on Eureka.

You may subscribe for the already available service, instead of running your own discovery service.

Here is the reference to PCF documentation:
https://docs.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-services/1-3/common/service-registry/